# Spring web service client for calling Apache axis web service

Tags: spring-ws

I need to call the external(Remote) web service through my spring web service client proramme.

- How can i send the request to remote web service service?

Comment: The docs should be clear, have you had a go reading them?

Answer (score 1):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html

Basically you can use the Spring webservice template for calling remote soap services.